# Does there exist an epimorphism from the ring $\mathbb{Z_{24}}$ onto the ring $\mathbb{Z_{7}}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Does there exist an epimorphism from the ring $\mathbb{Z_{24}}$ onto the ring $\mathbb{Z_{7}}$?

an epimorphism is a surjective homomorphism

Could someone give me an idea how to know this? to be honest I have no idea

Comment: Note that ring $\mathbb Z_7$ is a field.  You are asking if $\mathbb Z_7$ could be a quotient ring of $\mathbb Z_{24}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given any homomorphism $f:\Bbb Z_{24}\to\Bbb Z_7$, by definition of homomorphism we must have
$$
f(0)=f(24)=f(1+1+\cdots+1)\\
=f(1)+\cdots+f(1)
$$
where there are $24$ terms in each of the two long additions. Now, what could $f(1)$ possibly be? Which elements of $\Bbb Z_7$ are such that adding together $24$ copies of it gives $0$ (since $f(0)=0$)?

This argument actually doesn't use all of the ring structure, only the additive group. So the answer would be the same if we were asking about the groups $\Bbb Z_{24}$ and $\Bbb Z_7$.

Comment: $f(1)$  would be $f(1)=1$, then $f(24)=24$, Now, there is no number that added $24$ in $\mathbb{Z_{7}}$ so there could be no epimorphism

Comment: @Laliwis Be careful here. There _is_ an epimorphism $\Bbb Z_{24}\to\Bbb Z_6$. Make sure you understand what makes this proof work for $\Bbb Z_7$ but not for $\Bbb Z_6$.

Answer (score 0):

For another perspective, note that ring homomorphisms are always homomorphisms of the underlying additive groups. So if $f\colon \Bbb Z_{24}\to\Bbb Z_7$ is surjective, the first isomorphism theorem implies $7$ divides $24$. If you think about it, you can see how this is equivalent to Arthur's answer.

Comment: oh thanks i'll read that theorem

Comment: @Laliwis Lagrange's theorem and the isomorphism theorems are all pretty important. Yes, you really should.